# javascript auto call function in object

Tags: html, function, object, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I need to create a dynamic object. I'll store all of these objects in an array. Each object will have some property and objects. After the object is created, I need to do an auto execute method from it. I can't call in my code like this: `obj.doSomething` because some users have 2 objects, and other users 300 objects.

Something like this:

```
class Select {
    constructor(el,input){
        this.el = el; 
        this.input = input
    }

    AutoExecture(){
        // I need these function to execute immediately;
        console.log(this.input);
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can can `this.AutoExecture()` inside your constructor.

Comment: Thank you . That's what I needed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
class Select {
    constructor(el,input){
        this.el = el; 
        this.input = input;

        // This code will autoExecute when you construct an object
        console.log(this.input);
    }
}
```

You can run this code in the console with something like:

```
var a = new Select("hi", "bye");
```